# Mongodb $exist not working

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, exists

Ok I am not sure why this is not working I know the field is there because it has sub arrays in this mydetails field.

```
function firsttime($uid){
        $collection = static::db()->members;
        var_dump($collection->findOne(array("_id"=> new MongoId($uid), array("mydetails"=> array('$exists' => true)))));

    }
```

all it returns is NULL
is there a better way to find if there is or is not a field

in this example I want to see if the field mydetails exist?

It would be nice if I could either have a true or false return.

an example data

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("53b9ea3ae7fda8863c8b4568"),
  'mydetails' => 
  array (
    'name' => 
    array (
      'first' => 'Russell',
      'last' => 'Harrower',
    ),
    'email' => 'hidden@ipet.xyz',
    'birthday' => 
    array (
      'day' => '02',
      'month' => '02',
      'year' => '1988',
    ),
  )
)
```

Comment: Could you please post a complete document which should be found by this query?

Comment: @Philipp done for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got an `array(` too much in there. Try this:

```
$collection->findOne(array("_id"=> new MongoId($uid), "mydetails"=> array('$exists' => true)));
```